# Books on Hindu warriors

Tags: puranas, kshatriya

I am looking for a book which has stories of great Hindu warriors both from our epics and history

Comment: As one would expect, best place to find stories of heroes mentioned in epics would be epic themselves ! Unless you want to read their stories wearing different lens or POV in which case there is no dearth of alternate interpretation. So it would best if you can edit the question and remove epics from it. Then the question will be on hindu warriors who don't find mention in mainstream history texts, which would make more sense

Comment: Without having to go through all the epics .If there is just a compilation of short  stories of warriors ..Overcoming great challenges or fighting through adversity.

Answer (score 2):

This book describes in detail the heroism of Hindu warriors at the start of the era of Muslim invasions:

“Heroic Hindu Resistance to Muslim Invaders (636 AD to 1206 AD)”, Sita Ram Goel.

PDF link: http://www.hindustanbooks.com/pdfs/6493883-Heroic-Hindu-Resistance-to-Muslim-Invaders.pdf